# Is it possible to configure SAML settings in Google Domain automatically?

Tags: google-admin-sdk

is it possible to enable SSO to Google Apps automatically with super admin access?

Apps Admin Settings API supports only get and update of Single Sign-On settings, but I really need to enable/create these settings on behalf of a super admin.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think this [part](https://support.google.com/a/answer/60224?hl=en) of Google Apps Administrator Help can guide you regarding the Single Sign-On (SSO) for Google Apps accounts. It is explained here all the information that you need to know about SSO for Google Apps Support including how to set up Google service provider SAML with 3rd party IdPs. For more information, check this [link](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6087519?hl=en). NOTE: [The Admin Settings API is deprecated and is scheduled to be sunset on August 16, 2017](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/admin-settings/).

Comment: Thanks, I have already read that article. It's clear how to setup SSO for Google Apps **manually**.

Comment: But what I need is to activate SSO for 3rd partie's Google domain, to get access_token with granted access to whatever API, and activate SSO on behalf of the admin of that domain. 

Of cause, we can ask each admin to do it by hands, but it would be nice to simplify this process